# Do all integral domains have unity?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Does every integral domain have unity(1)?

If yes then how?  In many question involving integral domain, we use unit(1) element  of  ring.  Is this is true for every  integral domain?

Answer (score 2):

That's one of the axioms defining integral domains, so yes, that's true for every integral domain. Specifically:

> An integral domain is a nonzero commutative ring (with identity) in which the product of any two nonzero elements is nonzero.

And an axiom for commutative rings (with identity) is

> There exists an element $1$, such that for every $a$, we have $a\cdot 1=a$

Comment: A commutative ring need not have an identity element (for example, $2\mathbb Z$). But an integral domain is a commutative ring with identity and no zero divisors, so the existence of the identity element is **not** a consequence of the commutativity of the ring but rather is part of the definition of an integral domain.

Comment: @MPW $2\mathbb{Z}$ is not a ring, because it has no multiplicative identity. Read [the wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_(mathematics)#Definition) about this.

Comment: @vrugtehagel : You are wrong. A ring may or may not have an identity element. If it does, it is called a *ring with identity*. In fact, this is an exact example in Hungerford: "The set $E$ of even integers is a commutative ring without identity." Now, you may only be *interested* in rings with identity, but that is not a requirement of being a ring. (And I wouldn't ever rely on Wikipedia as a definitive source for technical mathematical facts.) You will note in the paragraph following your definition on Wikipedia that the author backpedals on the requirement of an identity.

Comment: @MPW quote from wikipedia: $R$ is a monoid under multiplication, meaning that: $(a\cdot b)\cdot c = a\cdot (b\cdot c)$ for all $a, b, c$ in $R$ ($\cdot $ is associative). There is an element $1$ in $R$ such that $a\cdot 1 = a$ and $1\cdot a = a$ for all $a$ in $R$ ($1$ is the multiplicative identity). Wikipedia is rarely wrong about such elementary subjects as they're written by professionals.

Comment: And I guess wolfram is wrong then too, see point (8) in [their list with ring axioms](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Ring.html)

Comment: @MPW, vrugtehagel: You're both wrong, to the extent you claim that the word "ring" has only one meaning. This word is sometimes used about structures that have an identity element, sometimes without this requirement -- it is simply a matter of convention, not one of absolute truth. Different authors follow different conventions (sometimes _the same_ author follows different conventions depending on his target audience), and one needs to be aware of this difference and be sure to know which convention any particular source is using.

Comment: It is a matter of what you are interested in talking about. You may tire of saying "ring with identity" and lump it into your definition of ring (which is what Wikipedia did). But it is ABSOLUTELY NOT A REQUIREMENT. I refer you to Hungerford, *Algebra* (Graduate Texts in Mathematics).

Comment: Fine, I'll edit my answer to distiguish between the different definitions a rang can have. I hope this clears things up.

Comment: Yes, @HenningMakholm is right. That's what I was saying. It's all part of what you lump into your definition. It is more precise to say "unless otherwise noted, all rings under discussion are assumed to be rings with identity" or something like that.

Comment: Well your "You are wrong" didn't seem like a "It's all part of what you lump into your definition", but we'll just call this discussion over. Multiple definitions are accepted, and as such, my answer clarifies which one I mean.

Comment: Just as an example for what people have pointed out above, Herstein (Topics in Algebra) defines rings without requiring existence of identity. He then defines integral domain as commutative ring with no zero divisors (still no identity requirement). Only later does he define principal ideal domain to be an integral domain WITH identity (which he calls "unit element") in which every ideal is principal. (This is needed so that every principal ideal in a p.i.d contains its generator, which gives you that every prime ideal is maximal, etc.)